# How to get all the sets of consecutive numbers that add up to form a number?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, math

I wanna create a program that generates sets of consecutive numbers that add up to form a number. For example. if the input number is 15, it should give -

```
7, 8
4, 5, 6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Some formula/algorithm/loop that can do something that fits in. It could generate an array or print it. This may seem a math problem or silly question but I can't actually figure out how to do that programmatically in Java.

Please try to give exact code that can do the thing.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: @AshishSingh I was trying to make a loop but I have no idea how to do this with it...

Comment: @VaibhavAgrawal: Why don't you show us your attempt? How are we supposed to help?

Comment: @Nikolas There's no attempt, I just can't figure out the algorithm to do it. I can write the code myself, but all I need is an idea or an algorithm to solve that problem. I spent hours thinking about it but I have ended up with nothing!

Comment: Consecutive numbers form arithmetic progression. Do you know anything about its sum?

Comment: @VaibhavAgrawal Dave gave the ideal logic to get the solution. I have made implementation of it in Java. Check the code and Try running it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll expand on @MBo's answer as it conveys a very clean algorithm. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) provides a good intro on arithmetic progressions, copied below for your convenience.

### Sum

[image: Sum]

### Derivation

[image]

The sum of a sequence starting with number `a` and consisting of `n` consecutive numbers:

S = (n/2) * [2 * a + (n-1) * d]

For consecutive numbers the step `d` is 1.

S = (n/2) * [2 * a + (n-1)]

Here we can transition to @MBo's post.

P = 2 * S = n * [2 * a + (n-1)]

We can iterate all possible counts of consecutive numbers `n` and check if the resulting `a` is valid (i.e. `a` is an integer).

Let's factor out `a`.

Say P = n * q => q = 2 * a + (n-1) => 2 * a = q - n + 1 => a = (q - n + 1) / 2

### Filters

1) we mentioned we could iterate all possible counts of consecutive numbers `n`, but given  `p = n * q` it's safe to say `n` needs to be a divisor of `p`.

- `p % n == 0`
- `nMax = (int)Math.sqrt(p)`

2) `a` is an integer and `a = (q - n + 1) / 2` => `(q - n + 1)` is even => `q - n` is odd.

- `((q - n) & 1) == 1`

### Implementation

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Progressions
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<List<Integer>> list = Calculate(15);
        System.out.print(list);
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> Calculate(int s)
    {
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int p = 2*s;
        int nMax = (int)Math.sqrt(p);
        for (int n=2; n<=nMax; n++) {
            if(p % n == 0) {
                int q = p / n;
                if(((q - n) & 1) == 1) {          
                    int a = (q - n + 1) / 2;
                    list.add(range(a,n));
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static List<Integer> range(int a, int n) {
        return IntStream.range(a, a+n)
            .boxed()
            .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Say your input is N. You know each set of k consecutive numbers will be centered around N/k. A solution exists for even k if N/k ends with 0.5, and odd k if N/k is an integer. The solution, if one exists, is the k integers centered around N/k.

```
k=1: 15/1 = 15, so 15 (trivial; may want to omit)
k=2: 15/2 = 7.5, so 7,8
k=3: 15/3 = 5, so 4,5,6
k=4: 15/4 = 3.75, so no solution
k=5: 15/5 = 3, so 1,2,3,4,5
k=6: 15/6 = 2.5, so 0,1,2,3,4,5 
etc...
k=15: 15/15 = 1, so -6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

You can easily modify this to limit to positive or nonnegative solutions.

Comment: Note that for valid values of k, you only need to check the divisors of N*2 (other than N*2 itself which is too big, and 1 which is trivial). E.g., for N=15, the divisors of 30 are 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15.

Answer (score 5):

Consecutive numbers form arithmetic progression. If it starts from number `a` and has `n` members, it's sum is

```
S = n * (2 * b + (n-1)) / 2
so
P = 2 * S = n * (2 * b + (n-1))
```

So for given input S we can factorize `2*S` into all possible pairs of integer factors `P = n * q` where `n<=q`, then get starting number

```
a = (q - n + 1) / 2
```

If a is integer (oddity of q and n differs) then pair `(a, n)` represents valid sequence starting from `a` with `n` members

Example for `S = 15, 2S = 30`:

```
30 = 2 * 15 => n = 2, a = 7  => (7,8)
30 = 3 * 10 => n = 3, a = 4  => (4,5,6)
30 = 5 * 6 =>  n = 5, a = 1  => (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Simple Python example:

```
import math
def getseqs(s):
    print(s)
    p = 2 * s
    for n in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(p))):
        if (p % n == 0):
            q = p // n
            if (((q - n) & 1) == 1):  #compare parity
                a = (q - n + 1) // 2
                seq = list(range(a, a+n))
                print(seq, sum(seq))

getseqs(17)
getseqs(15)
getseqs(72)

17
[8, 9] 17
15
[7, 8] 15
[4, 5, 6] 15
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 15
72
[23, 24, 25] 72
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] 72
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the `int input` is your input number (ex. `15`) and `List<int[]> list` as a storage of the result consecutive numbers, here you go:

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();                          

int lower = 1;                               // Start searching from 1
int upper = (int) Math.floor(input + 1 / 2); // Up to the half of input (8+9 > 15)
while (lower < upper) {                      // Iterate between the bounds
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {   // Iterate and sum the numbers
        sum += i;
        if (sum == input) {                  // If it matches the input
                                             // Add the range to the List
                                             // You have to loop them by one and add to the
                                             // List before version Java-8
            list.add(IntStream
                         .range(lower, i + 1)
                         .toArray());
            break;                           // Found, no reason to continue 
        }
        if (sum > input) {                   // Terminate the loop if the sum overlaps
            break;
        }
    lower++;                                 // Increment and try the sums from 
                                             // a higher starting number
    sum = 0;                                 // Reset the sum
}
```

The result for the input `15` is a `List` of these arrays:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8]
```

Comment: Nice one, I like it! +1

Comment: @Nikolas you can optimize the `sum += i` probably. Since, it's a series of consecutive numbers, it forms an arithmetic progression. So, all we need to find is how many terms in this AP to get the sum. So, a binary search between `lower` and `upper`  will do the trick.

Comment: @vivek_23: Thank you for the hint. I haven't been looking for the optimized solution but have assembled a naïve and working one from scratch.

Comment: @Nikolas The 'list' has a size of 1 and has just one number - 15 upon giving input as 15... What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a suggestion:

For an input number N:

- you only have to consider numbers between 1 and N.
- you can maintain an interval that represents the current subset of [1,...,N]. Maintain the sum of the current interval. The first interval will be [1,1], and its sum is 1.
- As long as the sum < N, increase the right end of the interval by one (for example, you start with the interval [1,1]. Since 1 < N, you extend it to [1,2].
- If the sum of the current interval is equal to N, you add that interval to the output, remove the left end of the interval (also removing it from the current sum), and continue.
- If the sum exceeds N, you also remove the left end of the interval (also removing it from the current sum), and continue.
- You finish when the interval becomes [N,N] (which is the final interval you should add to the output).

For the input 15, here's how the interval will change over time:

```
Interval        Sum

[1]             1
[1,2]           3
[1,2,3]         6
[1,2,3,4]       10
[1,2,3,4,5]     15 -> output [1,2,3,4,5]
[2,3,4,5]       14
[2,3,4,5,6]     20
[3,4,5,6]       18
[4,5,6]         15 -> output [4,5,6]
[5,6]           11
[5,6,7]         18
[6,7]           13
[6,7,8]         21
[7,8]           15 -> output [7,8]
[8]             8
[8,9]           17
[9]             9
[9,10]          19
[10]
...
[15]            15 -> output 15
```

You can probably make some optimization once the sum of two consecutive numbers becomes higher than the target sum, at which point you can terminate the loop, and just add the final set (which contains just the target sum).

Answer (score 1):

It used a [`Window Sliding Technique/Algorithm`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-sliding-technique/). You can also google `sliding window algorithm sum`.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing Implementation of the @Dave solution.
Try to Solve before asking... That's how we learn. (only if we can't get then ask)

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputNumber = s.nextInt();
    int k = 1;
    while(inputNumber/k >= .5){
        Float sequenceMid = (float) inputNumber/k;

        if( k%2 == 0 && (sequenceMid *2 == Math.ceil(sequenceMid *2)) ){
            for(int i = ((int)Math.floor(sequenceMid) - (k/2)),count=0 ; count < k ; count++,i++ ){
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }else if( (k%2 == 1) && (sequenceMid == Math.ceil(sequenceMid))){
            for(int i = (Math.round(sequenceMid) - ((k-1)/2)),count=0 ; count < k ; count++,i++ ){
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        k++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea that is similar to Eran's solution.

Since we're dealing with consecutive numbers, a cummulative sum (cumsum) can usually help.  The basic idea is that we want to find the difference between two cummulative sums that gives exactly K, where K is 15 in your example.

```
number:    1, 2, 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10
cumsum: 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55

differences:
15 - 0  = 15 -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
21 - 6  = 15 -> [4, 5, 6]
36 - 21 = 15 -> [7, 8]
```

The cummulative sum starts from 0 so we can do `15 - 0` subtraction.  The number included as the solution will be left-exclusive and right-inclusive.  That just means add 1 to the left index (index starts from 0).  Hopefully the pattern is quite clear.

The next task is to create an algorithm that does some sliding window with varying width across the cummulative sum.  The idea is to search for the difference with the exact value of K.  We can start at the beginning where the left and right side of the window points to 0.  While the difference is `<= K`, we want to increase the right side of the window, enlarging the window and the difference.

```
number:     1, 2, 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10
cumsum:  0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55
   1st: (]       -> 0 - 0 = 0
   2nd: (---]    -> 3 - 0 = 3
   3rd: (------] -> 6 - 0 = 0
```

Once the algorithm hit 15, it will print out the first answer, and then it will increase it one more time.  However, once we have the difference `> K`, we want to increase the left number, reducing the difference.

```
number:     1, 2, 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10
cumsum:  0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55
   1st: (-----------------]     -> 15 - 0 = 15 <print>
   2nd: (---------------------] -> 21 - 0 = 21
   3rd:     (-----------------] -> 21 - 1 = 20
```

Notice that the left side is bounded to be `< K/2` since `K//2 + (K//2 + 1) >= K` (where the equality is possible due to integer division denoted by `//`).  So we can stop the loop early when the left side reaches `K//2` (due to left-exclusive).

```
public static int cumsum(int index) {
    return index * (index + 1) / 2;
}

public static String printRange(int left, int right) {
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    buffer.append('[');
    for (int i=left+1;i<=right;i++) {
        buffer.append(i);
        buffer.append(',');
    }
    buffer.deleteCharAt(buffer.length()-1);
    buffer.append(']');
    return buffer.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int K = 15;

    int K_ov_2 = K/2;
    int left_index = 0;
    int right_index = 0;
    int diff;
    while (left_index < K_ov_2) {
        diff = cumsum(right_index) - cumsum(left_index);
        System.out.println("diff = " + diff + ", left = " + left_index + ", right = " + right_index);
        if (diff == K) {
            System.out.println(printRange(left_index,right_index));
        }

        if (diff <= K) {
            right_index++;
        } else {
            left_index++;
        }

    }

}
```

I added the debug line so the output can become more obvious.

```
diff = 0, left = 0, right = 0
diff = 1, left = 0, right = 1
diff = 3, left = 0, right = 2
diff = 6, left = 0, right = 3
diff = 10, left = 0, right = 4
diff = 15, left = 0, right = 5
[1,2,3,4,5]
diff = 21, left = 0, right = 6
diff = 20, left = 1, right = 6
diff = 18, left = 2, right = 6
diff = 15, left = 3, right = 6
[4,5,6]
diff = 22, left = 3, right = 7
diff = 18, left = 4, right = 7
diff = 13, left = 5, right = 7
diff = 21, left = 5, right = 8
diff = 15, left = 6, right = 8
[7,8]
diff = 24, left = 6, right = 9
```